# Where to Store database, different locations for different phones

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've a database named **plethora.db**. I am using this in my app. I've prepopulated the database through ***DB Browser for SQLite*** as I've too much data to enter and It's helpful and faster.

**Issue I'm facing:**

- Below is my code which works fine on almost every device and displays all the elements where id = 2 in `ListView` but `ListView` is blank in my   Honor 6x without any error in logcat.

**MyDatabase.java**

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {    
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "plethora.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public Cursor getNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();    
        String [] sqlSelect = {"2 _id", "Name"};
        String sqlTables = "Names";
        String selection = "_id = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { "2" };
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, selectionArgs,
                null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        names = db.getNames(); 

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                names,
                new String[] {"Name"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV2);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: `SQLiteAssetHelper` requires that the database be located at `app/src/main/assets/databases/` (lowercase `a` in `assets/`).

Comment: Mine is  Assets but it's working in other phones even in emulators.

Comment: Anyone can edit posts here, or at least propose edits. The edits have removed a number of typos and formatting errors, as well as cleaned up your use of tags and removed a little "noise." That's appropriate behavior here.